# Issue while trying to just change the metadata through ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

Im just a beginner trying to fix audio metadata in an mp4 video. I want to change the audio language code from German to English. Issue I encounter is that the output file always has changes done to the bitrates. I want the file to retain its original settings such as the file bitrate to be variable, output file's bitrate is constant. I've tried commands such as:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng OUTPUT.mp4

ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -metadata language=eng -c copy new.mp4
```

but cant seem to get a solution. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng output.mp4
```

- `-map 0` selects all streams. Otherwise it will use default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) which does not select all streams. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info on this option.
- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode to copy and paste the video and audio into the output. Because the streams are copied there will be no bitrate modification.
- `-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng` sets language to English for audio stream #0 (the first audio stream). If you wanted to set the language for the 2nd audio stream instead use `-metadata:s:a:1`.